# Schedule an Expo notification and cancel it an hour later?

Tags: android, expo, android-notifications, expo-notifications

Building an (Android) app for myself through Expo and React Native. I want to send scheduled time-sensitive notifications to the user (me). If the user hasn't interacted with a notification after an hour, it's irrelevant, so I would like to cancel the notification without the user needing to dismiss it. I would like to schedule many of these auto-dismiss notifications.

1. Doesn't look like there's a way to "schedule" a cancellation. Seems like I could use `setTimeout` and `cancelScheduledNotificationAsync` to cancel it after an hour. Is there a better way?
2. Even if `setTimeout` and `cancelScheduledNotificationAsync` works for the first notification I've scheduled, it seems like I could run into trouble with the second or third. That's a lot of time to be waiting in `setTimeout`. I'm worried about everything getting messed up if the device runs out of battery or something. Better ideas?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Is there any update on this topic?